# ¿Como separo un delimitador doble con IFS en bash?

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell, shell-script

Por ejemplo tengo la cadena:

```
IFS='!='
cadena="hola!=este=es\!un!=ejemplo=de!=IFS"
```

la imprimo con:

```
for subcadena in ${cadena};
do
    echo $subcadena 
done
```

estoy esperando que me arroje

```
hola
este
es
un
ejemplo
de
IFS
```

Pero al momento de imprimir me sale un espacio entre "hola" y "este" porque encuentra otro delimitador que es el `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
IFS='!=\' # agregamos \ al delimitador tambien

cadena="hola!=este=es\!un!=ejemplo=de!=IFS"

for subcadena in ${cadena};
do
    # validamos que la cadena no este vacia
    if [ ! -z "$subcadena" ]; then
        #imprimimos
        echo $subcadena
    fi
done
```

## resultado:

```
hola
este
es
un
ejemplo
de
IFS
```

Answer (score 1):

Según la ayuda de [`bash`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html):

> The shell treats each character of $IFS as a delimiter, and splits the
> results of the other expansions into words using these characters as
> field terminators

Es decir, se considera **cada** caracter como un delimitador, en tu caso, tanto el `=` y el `!` funcionan como delimitadores independientes y no como un grupo, lo que podemos apreciar fácilmente en este ejemplo:

```
IFS='!=';cadena="hola\!que=tal";for subcadena in ${cadena};do echo $subcadena; done

hola\
que
tal
te

va?
```

Answer (score 1):

Como te han dicho en las respuestas ya dadas, cada caracter dentro de la variable IFS se tomará como indicador independiente para indicar una separación.

Por otro lado, al definir tu variable IFS, te hace falta añadir el caracter "\".

Por el motivo de como se define la variable IFS, es que no puedes obtener lo que deseas si no es con el truco que uso @bryro, o la redefinición de tu problema, como lo hizo @patricio-moracho, para que se siga fielmente el uso de la definición de la varible IFS.

Yo te ofrezco otro truco que es poner el uso de un simple `tr`, a la salida de tu código, es decir:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='!=\'
#      |___ Añadimos este último caracter al IFS.

cadena="hola!=este=es\!un!=ejemplo=de!=IFS"

for subcadena in ${cadena}
do
    echo $subcadena 
done | tr -s "\n"
#     |_________|
#          |__ Añado esto.
```

Resultando en esto:

```
$ ./ifs.sh
hola
este
es
un 
ejemplo
de
IFS
```

Este uso de `tr` lo tomo porque, con el parámetro `-s`, el indicamos que elimine los caracteres repetidos (*squeeze*). En este caso hablamos del salto de línea repetido, debido a que tu cadena la definiste así.